# Unique values python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I am trying to basically look through a column and if that column has a unique value then enter 1 but if it doesn't it just becomes a NaN, my dataframe looks like this:

```
    Street             Number
0   1312 Oak Avenue     1
1   14212 central Ave   2
2   981 franklin way    1
```

the code I am using to put the number 1 next to unique values is as follows:

```
df.loc[(df['Street'].unique()), 'Unique'] = '1'
```

however when I run this I get this error KeyError: "not in index" I don't know why. I tried running this on the Number column and I get my desired result which is:

```
    Street            Number    Unique
0   1312 Oak Avenue     1         NaN
1   14212 central Ave   2          1
2   981 franklin way    1          1
```

so my column that specifies which ones are unique is called Unique and it puts a one by the rows that are unique and NaNs by ones that are duplicates. So in this case I have 2 ones and it notices that and makes the first NaN and the second it provides a 1 and since their is only 1 two then it provides us for a 1 their as well since it is unique. I just don't know why I am getting that error for the street column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really producing your desired result. The output of `df['Number'].unique()`, `array([1, 2], dtype=int64)`, just happened to be in the index. You'd encounter the same issue on that column if `Number` instead was `[3, 4, 3]`, say.

For what you're looking for, selecting where not `duplicated`, or where you have left after dropping duplicates, might be better than `unique`:

```
df.loc[~(df['Number'].duplicated()), 'Unique'] = 1
df
Out[51]: 
              Street  Number Unique
0    1312 Oak Avenue       1    1.0
1  14212 central Ave       2    1.0
2   981 franklin way       1    NaN


df.loc[df['Number'].drop_duplicates(), 'Unique'] = 1
df
Out[63]: 
              Street  Number  Unique
0    1312 Oak Avenue       1     NaN
1  14212 central Ave       2     1.0
2   981 franklin way       1     1.0
```